# Convert left join SQL query to HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have the following SQL query and wonder how to convert it to HQL. How would be the syntax?

```
select pr.PROD_ID, pr.ORG_UNIT_ID, pr.QTY, pr.ID from PROD_ST pr
left join
(select * from ORG_UNIT where code like '25%') org
on org.id = pr.ORG_UNIT_ID
where org.id = pr.ORG_UNIT_ID
```

Comment: entityManager.createQuery(
                "select pr.PROD_ID, pr.ORG_UNIT_ID, pr.QTY, pr.ID from PROD_ST pr" +
                        "left join" +
                        "(select * from ORG_UNIT where code like :value) org" +
                        "on org.id = pr.ORG_UNIT_ID" +
                        "where org.id = pr.ORG_UNIT_ID", OrgUnit.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first, your Sql `LEFT JOIN`, really is a `INNER JOIN`, because in the `WHERE` clause you have put:

```
org.id = pr.ORG_UNIT_ID
```

The second, in your SELECT field list you show only pr fields, so you can convert your LEFT JOIN with the EXISTS function like this (I'm supposing you have for each table an entity with same name):

```
SELECT pr.PROD_ID, pr.ORG_UNIT_ID, pr.QTY, pr.ID from PROD_ST pr
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'ORG_UNIT'
    FROM ORG_UNIT org
    WHERE org.code like '25%'
    AND org.id = pr.ORG_UNIT_ID
)
```

Comment: I could not retrieve the intended results by modifying my query with yours.
However, my question is not to change my query but to convert it in hibernate query. I will edit and write the code that I try now for you to be able to see it